# Rellenar input con información de la base de datos angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un input text

```html
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hojaIngresoMedica.periodoSeguimiento" [value]="hojaingreso[0].periodoSeguimiento" [placeholder]="hojaingreso[0].periodoSeguimiento" [disabled]="modificar == false">
```

Con este formulario inserto unos datos en mi base de datos, al volver a entrar quiero mostrar los datos insertados en la base de datos, hasta ahora se muestra en el placeholder, pero claro es el placeholder...

Comment: La base de datos la tienes con el propio Angular o tienes algún tipo de Api al que llamar para obtener los datos? Simplemente con ese trozo de código no te podemos ayudar mucho.

Comment: Tengo una api en php

Comment: Pues en ese caso tienes que hacer una llamada a esa Api para obtener los datos, y hacer un bindeo de esos datos en el input.

Comment: Ya obtengo los datos en un array ``this.hojaingreso[0].nombredelcampo`` ahí tengo el dato